# firebase auth management in ios

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am working with firebase in ios using swift. After login into application, I am getting data from my firebase database which fine. Now if I close my application without logout and re run after some time like 30 min or about an hour I can see my user is logged in but data is not coming from database. After I logout and login again data shows up. 
Following is my code to check if user is logged in or not after that I perform operation to get data.

```
if Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid == nil{

        print("Logout call")
        perform(#selector(handleLogout), with: nil, afterDelay: 0)
    }else{
        print("User Logged In")
        fethUser()
    }
```

After a certain period of time when I run application ,I can see the message "User Logged In", but data is not getting fetch.
I think this is happening because of session or token time out. If that is the case, then how can I persist login information on my application? Like paytm or other applications are doing they don't need to login everytime we used application.

Please let me know if there is any problem with post. Thank you in advance.

Comment: When is this check being performed? Also, you may want to change to *if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil* and ensure it's being called in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions. Be sure to include *addStateDidChangeListener* and remember that *currentUser* might be nil because the auth object has not finished initializing. Take look at the [Manage Users](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users) for some best practices. It's going to be hard to really answer as there's not enough code to see what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

The Firebase Token gets disabled after one hour or so. You need to enable Token Service API to allow refreshing the token once it expires. Go to https://console.developers.google.com/ , click onto "Enable APIs And Services", search for Token Service API and enable it.
If you want your app to perform auto login, you can use KeychainAccess https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/KeychainAccess.  So users won't need to login every time they launch the app.